# Apache 2.2 umask in FreeBSD

Tags: apache-2.2, freebsd, umask

I have Apache 2.2 running under FreeBSD 7 (and 8). It runs with the system default umask of 022, and I need it to be 002 so that www group members can make changes without having to chase it with chmod.

I put www into a login class with an overridden umask, which did not work.

How can I force a umask of 002 in Apache, independent of how Apache is launched (rc.d or apachectl, etc).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user

Answer (score 1):

You seek the assistance of [mod_umask](http://www.outoforder.cc/projects/apache/mod_umask/) (not, to my knowledge, available in ports - haven't gone on an extensive search though).

Answer (score 0):

If you have `www` user, try to make to him a home directory then open `/home/www/.bashrc`
and set default `umask` you want.